# Why is using global in python threading bad practice?

Tags: python, multithreading, global

I read all over various websites how using global is bad. I have an application where I am storing say, 300 objects, in an array. I want to have 8 threads running through these 300 objects. These objects are different sizes, say between 10 and 50,000 integers and randomly distributed (think worst case scenario here).

Basically, I want to start up 8 threads, do a process on an object, report or store the results, and pick up a new object, 300 times.

The solution I can think of is to set a global lock and a global counter, lock the array, get the current object, increment the counter, release the lock.

There is 1 lock for 8 threads. There is 1 counter for 8 threads. I have 2 global objects. I store results in a dictionary, possibly also global to make it visible to all threads but also threadsafe. I am not bothering to do something stupid like subclassing thread and passing along 300/8 objects to each object because multiprocessing.pool does that for me. So how would you do it? Also, convince me that using global in this situation is bad.

Answer (score 2):

Classifying approaches as either "good" or "bad" is a bit simplistic -- in practice, if a design makes sense to you and accomplishes the goals you set out to accomplish, then it doesn't matter whether other people (except possibly your boss) think it's "good" or not; it either works or it doesn't.  On the other hand, if your design causes you a lot of pain and suffering, that's a sign that you might not be using the most suitable design for the task at hand.

That said, there are some valid reasons why a lot of people think that global variables are problematic, particularly when combined with multithreading.

The general problem with global variables (with or without multithreading) is that as your program grows larger, it becomes increasingly difficult to mentally keep track of which parts of your program might be reading and/or updating the global variables' values at which times -- since they are global, by definition all parts of your program have access to them, so when you're trying to trace through your program to figure out who it was who set a global variable to some unexpected value, the list of suspects can become unmanageably large.  (this isn't much of a problem for small programs, but the larger your program grows, the worse this problem becomes -- and a lot of programmers have learned, through painful experience, that it's better to nip the problem in the bud by avoiding globals wherever possible in the first place, then to have to go back and rewrite a big, complicated, buggy program later on)

In the specific use-case of a multithreaded program, the anybody-could-be-accessing-my-global-variable-at-any-time property becomes even more fraught with peril, since in a multithreaded scenario, any (non-immutable) data that is shared between threads can only be safely accessed with proper serialization (e.g. by locking a mutex before reading/writing the shared data, and unlocking it afterwards).  Ideally programmers would never accidentally read or write any shared+mutable data without locking the mutex -- but programmers are human and will inevitably make mistakes; if given the ability to do so, sooner or later you (or someone else) will forget that access to a particular global variable needs to be serialized, and will just go ahead and read/write it, and then you're in for a lot of pain, because the symptoms will be rare and random, and the cause of the fault won't be obvious.

So smart programmers try to make it impossible to fall into that sort of trap, usually by limiting access to the shared-state to a specific, small, carefully-written set of functions (a.k.a. an API) that implement the serialization correctly so that no other code has to.  When doing that, you want to make sure that *only* the code in this particular API has access to the shared data, and that nobody else does -- something that is impossible to do with a global variable, as by definition everyone has direct access to it.

There is also one performance-related reason why people prefer not to mix global variables and multithreading:  the more serialization you have to do, the less your program can exploit the power of multiple CPU cores.  In particular, it does you no good to have an 8-core CPU if 7 of your 8 threads are spending most of their time blocked, waiting for a mutex to become available.

So how does that relate to globals?  It's related in that in most cases it's difficult or impossible to prove that a global variable won't ever be accessed by another thread, which means all accesses to that global variable need to be serialized.  With a non-global variable, on the other hand, you can make sure to give a reference to that variable to only a single thread -- at which point you have effectively guaranteed that only that one thread will ever access the variable (since the other threads have no references to it, you know they can't access it), and because you have that guarantee, you no longer need to serialize access to that data, and now your thread can run more efficiently because it never has to block waiting for a mutex.

(Btw note that CPython in particular suffers from a severe form of implicit serialization caused by Python's [Global Interpreter Lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), which means that even the best multithreaded, CPU-bound Python code will be unlikely to use more than a single CPU core at a time.  The only way to get around that is to use multiprocessing instead, or do the bulk of your program's computations in a lower-level language such C, so that it can execute without holding the GIL)

Comment: Right. I understand all of that. what I still don't quite understand is how to get around it. I have 8 threads going through an array of objects with random sizes. If I have all global variables located in a single py file that starts each of the threads, has a getNext() function, and then 1 process with that entry, I am following the standard threading template. In Java, I would use syncronize but we don't have that.

What I find even more confusing is this concept that threads will lock. Obviously. I have a protected resource (read/write). I expect threads to block. That is how they work.

Comment: If your current approach is working for you, then you might as well use it -- there's no point in making your program more complex simply to satisfy the aesthetic preferences of strangers.  If you feel the need to change the design for yourself, OTOH, you could look into a threadpool-based design, where the "main/master thread" spawns a number of "worker threads" and uses message-passing to hand out a "job-message" to each worker and the worker sends back a "results-message" reply when the job is done (and repeat until all the work has been completed).  No globals required for that design.

Comment: I believe a lot of the “bad aesthetics” of global locks have to do with the core principle that in any program you write you do not want to flood the namespace with global variables and also that global variables are also a bit harder to track down because they could be anywhere in your code rather than locally scoped.